# (parameter) label: any Binding element 'label' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

I am copying [an example from react-hook-form](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/examples/V7/customInput.tsx), however it gives me the error:

```
(parameter) label: any
Binding element 'label' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)
```

The example:

```
const options = [
      { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
      { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
      { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
    ];
    
    const MyInput = ({ label, name, onChange, onBlur, ref }) => {
      return (
        <>
          <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
          <input
            name={name}
            placeholder="Jane"
            onChange={onChange}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            ref={ref}
          />
        </>
      );
    };
```

Gives me the following error:

```
(parameter) label: any
Binding element 'label' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)
```

After adding the types the error still persists:

```
interface InputProps {
    label: string,
    name: string,
    onChange: any,
    onBlur: any,
    ref: any
}

  const MyInput = ({ label, name, onChange, onBlur, ref }):InputProps => {
    return (
      <>
        <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
        <input
          name={name}
          placeholder="Jane"
          onChange={onChange}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          ref={ref}
        />
      </>
    );
  };
```

I'm using nextjs I dunno if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Had the props in the wrong place I think, this seemed to fix it:

```
  const MyInput = ({ label, name, onChange, onBlur, ref }: InputProps) => {
    return (
      <>
        <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
        <input
          name={name}
          placeholder="Jane"
          onChange={onChange}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          ref={ref}
        />
      </>
    );
  };
```